# Optimize WP site for millions of posts

Tags: database, performance

I have a news portal Using WP cms, It has around 90K posts. DB size 2GB. Used Apache, ngnix,

WP Memory Limit 4096M, Time 300 Sec, Using CDN :)

I am using 2 Dedicated servers E5 2650 V4, 96GB Ram. and 2650V4 32GB for Database.

My site is doing fine, Dashboard and site both are faster, but the problem is when I try to add/Edit/Update/publish Post It has taken a long time, like 40 Second to 1.20 Minute.

I have optimized DB lot of times, Changed to the default theme, check all plugin, There is no conflict. If I use default theme 2017 and deactivate all plugin,  same problem.

Can anyone give me better suggestion?

Comment: Do you have revisions enabled? Turning them off and then actually going in and deleting the old revisions will save a ton of space if they have been on and you can live with having them off.

Comment: A lot of the things that will help you here have more to do with Mysql dev ops than WP, e.g. using innodb tables instead of MyISAM. Are you sure that it's the updating of the database that's taking all the time? At those post counts the queries you run have more of an impact than the posts themselves

Comment: Additional information request from your DATABASE server. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Comment: It's possible you have many thousands of users. Editing slows down when you have many users, because WordPress's way of finding administrator/ editor / author users is slow. Try this new plugin, it addresses that issue.  https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-users-for-speed/